# Javascript Split, Replace acting strange

Tags: javascript, string, join, replace, split

I am trying to format a string into word+word+word

For example

"ultra music festival" into "ultra+music+festival"

I have tried using following codes

```
query.split(" ").join("+");
```

or

```
query.replace(" ", "+");
```

however, both ways will give me

"ultra+music festival"

what is causing this issue, and how can i fix it ?

Comment: Hmm, are you sure your test case is correct? This appears to be working for me:
var query = "ultra music festival";
var str = query.split(" ").join("+");
console.log(str); //ultra+music+festival

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the global attribute is important.

Example!

```
var str = "Mr Blue has a blue house and a blue car"; 
var res = str.replace(/blue/g, "red");
```

in this case:

```
query.replace(/ /g, "+");
```

Answer (score 1):

The first version (`split`/`join`) should work as-is (if the second space is really a space).

To replace more than one space using `replace()`, you'll need the `g` flag:

```
 query.replace(/ /g, "+");
```

To replace multiple spaces (or tabs, or other whitespace) in a row, you'd use:

```
 query.replace(/\s+/g, "+");
```

so that `"one     two three"` would still turn into `"one+two+three"`.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Good point; normally I'd use `\s+/g`, but wanted to keep the number-of-explanations-needed down to a minimum here.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Added an example of that usage to the answer. Thanks.